# File not found exception but it is in the same folder/package

Tags: java, readfile, filenotfoundexception

I have a problem. In my program in one package there are a class Firma.
At the constructor of this class I read some information out of a text file named 'firmendaten.fd'. The textfile is also located at the same package, but if I try to read i get a `FileNotFoundException`.

The code which produces the error:

```
public Firma(){
    BufferedReader in = null; 
    try { 
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Firmendaten.fd")); 
        name = in.readLine();
        zusatz = in.readLine();
        strasse = in.readLine();
        hnr = in.readLine();
        plz = in.readLine();
        ort = in.readLine();
        bank = in.readLine();
        iban = in.readLine();
        bic = in.readLine();
        steuerNr = in.readLine();
        steuersatz = in.readLine();
        chef = in.readLine();
        zahlungsziel = in.readLine();

    } catch (IOException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } finally { 
        if (in != null) 
            try { 
                in.close(); 
            } catch (IOException e) { 
            } 
    } 
    }
```

The error it produces:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Firmendaten.fd (Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of errors but post them in text form, i.e. the code that produces the error (unless it's too much) and the error itself.

Comment: try using the absolute path of the file when you pass it in instead of just the name

Comment: if i use the absolute path it's fine, but the absolute path is bad code, because if the programm is located somewhere else it throws this exception  again.

Comment: You're readng a file. That has nothing to do with packages. Relative paths start with the current directory, i.e. the directory from which the java command is executed. Just like `less foo.txt` reads the foo.txt file in the curretnt directory. If you want to load a resource from the classpath, then don't use file IO. Use `Firma.class.getResourceAsStream("Firmendaten.fd")`

Comment: the command is executed at Rechnungsprogramm\src\main\Firma.java
the file which should be read is Rechnungsprogramm\src\main\Firmendaten.fd

so in my mind the relative path should be Firmendaten.fd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar-ish problem recently so I used the location of the .jar file of which the program was running.

```
        String path = Class.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
        path = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        String decodedPath = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");
        return decodedPath;
```

Then I called the file like:

```
File file = new File(userPath + "\\yourfile.txt");
```

Note that this was taken from a mix of answers on here, so hopefully may help you.

Comment: at the codeline:

String path = Class.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();



if i use your code snippet

Comment: I have found the mistake i made at using your snippet